# How to call a trigger in a Apex Trigger Unit Test?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have an after insert/update trigger that on an object called `Call_Report__c`. The after trigger (upon save) sets the field of the `Call_Report__c` object. I'm not sure how to test it since I don't know how to make sure the trigger is being fired. I saw something on trailhead `Database.Delete Result = Database.delete(acct, false)` but can this apply in my situation? Is there one for `update` and `insert`? How do I distinguish before/after?

This is what I have so far for my test:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class CallReportTriggerTest {

    @isTest static void testSetFieldsMethod() {
        Call_Report__c callReport = new Call_Report__c();
        callReport.Loan_Apps_to_Relate__c = 'a071F00000A99Z4QAJ,a071F00000A99YpQAJ';
        Loan_Application__c loanAppRelate = new Loan_Application__c(Id = 'a071F00000A99Z4QAJ');
        Loan_Application__c loanAppRelate1 = new Loan_Application__c(Id = 'a071F00000A99YpQAJ');
        insert callReport;

        System.assertEquals(callReport.Id, loanAppRelate.Call_Report__c);
        System.assertEquals(callReport.Id, loanAppRelate1.Call_Report__c);
    }
}
```

Currently the tests fail saying actual is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your trigger logic would help quite a bit, but It's worth noting that hard-coding Ids in your tests is typically a bad idea.

Your best bet would be to actually create and insert your Loan_Application__c records before inserting your Call_Report__c record.

Then, you'll have to re-query your Call_Report__c record to get any field updates that happened in your trigger.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by `re-query`?

Comment: Nevermind, got it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Test methods by default cannot see pre-existing records in an org. The test method itself should insert the records it needs. So this code:

```
callReport.Loan_Apps_to_Relate__c = 'a071F00000A99Z4QAJ,a071F00000A99YpQAJ';
Loan_Application__c loanAppRelate = new Loan_Application__c(Id = 'a071F00000A99Z4QAJ');
Loan_Application__c loanAppRelate1 = new Loan_Application__c(Id = 'a071F00000A99YpQAJ');
insert callReport;
```

will not work. Instead you will need to insert the `Loan_Application__c` records and set the actual Id values in the `Loan_Apps_to_Relate__c` field.

Also note that *one:many* relationships are usually implemented by the *many* side holding a reference (via an Id) of the *one* side, rather than the *one* side holding a collection of references (via Ids) to the *many* side.